# highlighting different parts of a string in different color in r shiny ui

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have an output string that's a full url, and I want to highlight different parameters in that url in different colors. I tried a few different approaches of splitting the string up in server.R then trying to join them in ui.R and apply different CSS classes but without success...the link looks like this

http://www.example.com?utm_campaign=**[blue text]**&utm_source=**[red text]**

When I try to combine different parts of the URL passed from server.R it creates spaces in the final URL.

Here's some sample code

In server.R

```
output$val1 <-  renderText({"http://www.example.com?utm_campaign="})
output$val2 <-  renderText({"[Enter campaign name]"})
```

in ui.R

```
p(textOutput("val1"), span(textOutput("val2"), style = "color:blue"), "more text" )
```

This breaks the outpout in to two lines

Comment: It would really help if you posted a bit of relevant code, especially the lines that create the parts of the URL/pass it around, so that we can see what you're doing and why there are spaces

Comment: Thanks - added some code to show what I mean

Answer (score 1):

The sample code you provided creates newlines, not just spaces for me. If that's what you're trying to solve then here is the solution for that: Add `inline = TRUE` as a parameter to the `textOutput`. Or if you're using an old version of shiny that doesn't support that, add `display: inline;` using CSS.

`p(textOutput("val1", inline = TRUE), span(textOutput("val2", inline = TRUE), style = "color:blue"), "more text" )`

I usually look at the HTML output from a shiny app to see what's going on to figure out why things are rendered the way they are, that's how I went about this.

You'd notice that there is still a gap between successive `<span>` elements.  If that's what you were referring to before, then that is a more complex problem and even in pure HTML/CSS there isn't a beautiful solution, let alone in Shiny.  For example see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).

Here is one possible way to overcome this, which I admit isn't very pretty. There are likely other ways to achieve this, but here's the first solution I could think of, borrowing ideas from that CSS question thread. Th main idea is to use `font-size:0` on the parent and restore the original font-size for the spans.

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML("
    #val2 {
      color: blue;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 0;
    }
    p > * {
      font-size: 14px;
    } 
  "))
),

p(textOutput("val1", inline = TRUE), textOutput("val2", inline = TRUE), span("more text"))
```

Hope this helps